# Bash - How To Manipulate Response All To One Line?

Tags: string, bash, shell, net-snmp

I am using the bash script below to get these values from my server and I want to text these to myself. The only problem is when it runs it does something like in java println rather than print.

How can I put the response all on the same line like

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2 = STRING: "Dell Lat i17" 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4 = STRING: "888.888.1234"
```

rather than the output below?

**Input:**

```
OUTPUT=`snmpget 172.0.0.1 -c public -v 1  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6'
echo $OUTPUT
```

**Output**:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2 = STRING: "Dell Lat i17"
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4 = STRING: "888.888.1234"
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6 174 days, 6:22:10.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't quote your variable, the shell will put them all on the same line, so your command should work:

```
OUTPUT=`snmpget 172.0.0.1 -c public -v 1 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6`
echo "Multiple lines: $OUTPUT"
echo Single line: $OUTPUT
```

You can also do this without the variable, by replacing line feeds with spaces:

```
snmpget 172.0.0.1 -c public -v 1 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2 ... | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Failing to quote `$OUTPUT` will produce unintended output if `snmpget` returns any wildcard characters. +1 for the `tr`-based solution, though.

Comment: And splitting of unquoted variable depends on IFS containing '\n', which is generally expected, but doesn't look like OP has from his i/o.

Answer (score 0):

Using inline field separator set to '" '

```
IFS='" ' read -ra $OUTPUT <<< "$IN"
for i in "${OUTPUT[@]}"; do
  echo $i
done
```